# Manipulate data in MS Excel based on a pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with data in the pattern below

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| 00-99-00 | CarName |
| 123456 | ModelNumber |
| street | name |
| bld | addr |
| country | code |

I have the list full of data in sets of 6 rows like above repeating with same pattern. I only want to retain the third row from each set and delete everything else. Can anyone help me in doing with (preferable using excel itself)?

Comment: you cannot delete row using Formula, But you can manipulate and create a filter, use the filter to delete the data

Answer (score 0):

Since it's always the same pattern, try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(A1:B18,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A18)/6,,3,6))
```

Comment: Doesn't give desired result. Are you sure the formula is correct?

```#NAME?```

Comment: @darecoder, yes, it's correct. Ms365 is required though.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that. I am actually trying to parse the data from https://standards-oui.ieee.org/ for all the standard OUIs. I need to have records of OUI and company names.

Comment: @darecoder, if you want to proceed by formula then maybe `=INDEX(A:A,ROW(1:1)*6-3)` in `D2` and drag one right and further down assuming the same setup as per my screenshot.